# SimpleNLG - Creating a 2 part sentence using "placeholders"

Tags: nlp, text-analysis

Does anyone know how to (using SimpleNLG) create a proper "two part" sentence like so (I'm not a linguist so I'm not exactly sure what syntactic categories each word/phrase:

> "I bought **a new widget engine**, which created **product A, product B, and product C**."

The text in bold will be inserted dynamically at runtime by a syntactic parser or something else. I went through the SimpleNLG tutorial (there doesn't seem to be anything else that's more in-depth) and subsequently tried to attach a PPPhraseSpec object (representing the second part of the sentence above) to a SPhraseSpec (which has a nounphrase and verbphrase), but the result is incomprehensible and is grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution for your problem: the first part in bold is a grammatical object (a noun phrase) and the second part in bold is an object to the verb "create" (coordinate clause).

```
import simplenlg.realiser.english.Realiser;
import simplenlg.lexicon.Lexicon;
import simplenlg.phrasespec.*;
import simplenlg.framework.*;
import simplenlg.features.*;


public class Test {

    // Target:
    // I bought a new widget engine, 
    //   which created product A, product B, and product C.

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting...");
        Lexicon lexicon = Lexicon.getDefaultLexicon();
        NLGFactory nlgFactory = new NLGFactory(lexicon);
        Realiser realiser = new Realiser(lexicon);

        SPhraseSpec s1 = nlgFactory.createClause("I",
            "bought", "a new widget engine");
        s1.setFeature(Feature.TENSE, Tense.PAST);

        SPhraseSpec s2 = nlgFactory.createClause("", "created");
        NPPhraseSpec object1 = nlgFactory.createNounPhrase("product A");
        NPPhraseSpec object2 = nlgFactory.createNounPhrase("product B");
        NPPhraseSpec object3 = nlgFactory.createNounPhrase("product C");

        CoordinatedPhraseElement cc = nlgFactory.createCoordinatedPhrase();
        cc.addCoordinate(object1);
        cc.addCoordinate(object2);
        cc.addCoordinate(object3);

        s2.setObject(cc);
        s2.setFeature(Feature.TENSE, Tense.PAST);

        s2.setFeature(Feature.COMPLEMENTISER, ", which"); // non-restrictive?
        s1.addComplement(s2);

        String output = realiser.realiseSentence(s1);
        System.out.println(output);
    }

}
```

I am not a native English speaker and often get this part wrong, but I think you want a restrictive relative clause instead of a non-restrictive one: "I bought a new widget engine that created..." instead of "I bought a new widget engine, which created ..." If that is the case, just comment the line setting the complementiser.